# Current questions counts based on close state, answered and score and about Roomba

Tags: discussion, statistics

Based on the quality of some of the new question we see every day, some users think we collect trash here on Arduino SE. But we don't collect it all really. Stack Exchange system has a cleaning process nicknamed Roomba (as the robotic vacuum cleaner). Roomba deletes closed question without answer 10 days after asked. Roomba deletes unanswered questions with negative score 30 days after asked.

Today I made for me an overview of questions count based on close state, answered and score. There were 23764 questions total at that time. I used advanced search with queries like `closed:yes answers:0 duplicate:no score:1..1`.

**Questions (not closed) with at least one answer:**

| score | count | % of all questions |
| --- | --- | --- |
| score 2 or more | 4570 | 19% |
| score 1 | 5253 | 22% |
| score 0 | 7432 | 31% |
| negative score | 1189 | 5% |

**Questions (not closed) without answers:**

| score | count | comment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| score 1 or more | 2877 | 13% of all questions |
| score 0 | 462 | one dovnwote will make them ready for deletion |
| negative score | 26 | roomba will delete them soon if no upvote happens |

**Closed questions (not duplicates) without answer:**

| score | count | comment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| score 2 or more | 42 |  |
| score 1 | 151 | one dovnwote will make them ready for deletion |
| score 0 or less | 57 | roomba will delete them soon if no upvote happens |

We have 437 questions marked as duplicate. Roomba only deletes "closed as duplicate" questions with negative score and no answer. There are 121 duplicate questions for which one dovnwote will make them ready for deletion.

We have 1177 closed (not as duplicate) questions with an answer. It is 5% of all questions.

**Voting on questions is important. Their score decides the deletion. Many times one vote makes a difference.**

Comment: If anyone is interested, then the *full conditions* to the Roomba cleanup are here: [The Community user deleted my question! What gives?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba)

Comment: and even a Roomba Forecaster user script exists https://stackapps.com/questions/7239/roomba-forecaster-when-will-the-question-be-roombaed-if-it-wont-why